# awk to generate consecutive sequence:

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to read first field then generate sequence based on "&-" and "&&-" delimiter.

```
Ex: If Digits field is  210&-3 ,  need to populate 210 and 213 only.
      If Digits field is  210&&-3 , need to populate 210,211,212 and 213.
```

Input.txt

```
DIGITS                    

  20
  210&-2     
  2130&&-3&-6&&-8
```

Desired Output:

```
DIGITS
  20
  210
  212
  2130
  2131
  2132
  2133
  2136
  2137
  2138
```

Have tried some commands but not materialised, any suggestions...

Comment: Bash, Python, Perl, … answers would not be appreciated?

Comment: YUK! What produces this mess? :-)

Comment: Is `123&&-34` → `123 124 … 1233 1234` a case?

Comment: @MarkSetchell if seen this pattern a lot. E.g. librarians like to write "pp. 123 to 5" for no apparent reason.

Comment: Kay, Bash is ok , dont have access Python and perl

Comment: kay , samples will have separated  in single digits only  0-9 only, will not have &&34 , &34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="&" }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i == "") {
            i++
            $i = $1 - $i
            for (j=(prev+1);j<$i;j++) {
                print j
            }
        }
        else if ($i < 0) {
            $i = $1 - $i
        }

        print $i
        prev = $i
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
20
210
212
2130
2131
2132
2133
2136
2137
2138
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an awk executable script version:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS="[&]"}

{
    flen = length($1)
    ldigit = substr($1, flen)+0
    prefix = substr($1, 1, flen-1)+0

    if( ldigit !~ /[[:space:]]/ )
         print prefix ldigit

    doRange=0
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        if( $i == "" ) { doRange=1; continue }
        if( !doRange ) { ldigit=-$i; print prefix ldigit }
        else {
            while( ldigit < -$i ) {
                ldigit++
                print prefix ldigit
            }
            doRange=0
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the breakdown:

- Set the field separator to `&`
- When their are commands to parse, break find the `prefix` and the `ldigit` values
- Print out the first value using `print prefix ldigit`.  This will print the header too.  The `if( ldigit !~ /[[:space:]]/ )` discards the blank lines
- When there's no range, set `ldigit` and then `print prefix ldigit`
- When there is a range, increment `ldigit` and `print prefix ldigit` for as long as required.

Using an older gawk version I get output like:

```
DIGITS
  20
  210
  212
  2130
  2131
  2132
  2133
  2136
  2137
  2138
```

Comment: I think you asked this question before, where there were other fields past the range notation.  If you have blank-space delimited data too, this same code will work if changed from using `FS` to a `split()` on `&` ( along with some corresponding changes to use the split array ).

Comment: I noticed I wasn't using the correct input data exactly.  I've updated my script to account for the header and blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `awk` for [patsplit](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html#index-patsplit_0028_0029-function-_0028gawk_0029):

```
gawk '{
    n = patsplit($0,patt,/[&][&]-|[&]-/,number); 
    lastnum = number[0]
    print lastnum
    if(n > 0) {
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            if (patt[i] ~ /^[&]-$/) {
                print number[0] + number[i]
                lastnum = number[0] + number[i]
            }
            if (patt[i] ~ /^[&][&]-$/) {
                for (num = lastnum + 1; num <= number[0] + number[i]; num++) {
                    print num
                }
                lastnum = number[0] + number[i]
            }
        }
    }
}' file
```

**Output**

```
20
210
212
2130
2131
2132
2133
2136
2137
2138
```